Migrate from material design to Material 3, material3 components are not available
I'm updating an app to Material Design 3, I'm going from
com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0-alpha01
androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1

to
androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.2.1
androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1

And I'm experiencing weird problems, namely I expect the app to "break" because the themes and styles are referencing Theme.MaterialComponents.NoActionBar etc rather than Theme.Material3. But when I try to reference Theme.Material3 the IDE/gradle build doesn't recognize that component.
So Why didn't the previous implementation of material break when I removed the previous dependency?
I tried invalidating the cache and restarting etc. The app still builds and I can run it on my device as if nothing changed, so I think the dependencies were never picked up by gradle in the first place, but invalidating the cache and rm caches didn't do anything to help. I also tried removing appcompat but that didn't change anything, which similarly should of broken lots of things I think.

Heads up: androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.2.1 is not remotely related to what you're actually using currently - this is the Jetpack Compose (a declarative approach to UIs) implementation of the Material3 specification. You should instead be sticking with com.google.android.material:material if you're not planning to use Compose, and just update to use the latest version.
The Material3 theme was first introduced in 1.5.0, but you should preferably be using the latest stable version, which is 1.11.0 as of the time of writing:
implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.11.0") // Or set via Gradle Version Catalogs

